# How can I use the results of a query in VBA to update a table?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am sure I am approaching this incorrectly since there has to be a design issue with the database but I am willing to try anything right now.

On a form I have a main subform containing a drop down of different types of lands and two buttons (Prev and Next). This subform data source is a table called Section22_PMLU

Nested in this subform is another subform linked to the parent subform using the PMLU_Code. This data is being updated to table Section22_Data.

When a user clicks the drop down on the parent subform and makes a land selection and then chooses details (characteristics of land) in the child subform this data is correctly displayed in the Data table. Even if the user clicks the drop down again (w/out creating a new record) and adds child records this is reflected in the data table.

The issue is with the PMLU table. If I initally make a selection and add data from nested subform this record is recorded/displayed in the PMLU table. If I click in the drop down field and click "Add New Record" or press Ctrl+ and then choose a new item from drop down - it is recorded/displayed correctly in the table. HOWEVER if I make a selection without creating a new record first this item copies over the one added previously. WHen I attempt to go back (prev button) to see the record it is not displayed. However it is still in the data table.

In order to correct this issue I have to go directly into the PMLU table and add the missing PMLU codes that match the PMLU codes found in the data table.

If I run the following query I get those missing PMLU's. How can I use the results to populate the PMLU table with the missing codes

```
SELECT Section22_2_Data.PMLU_Code, Section22_2_Data.PMLUType
FROM Section22_2_Data LEFT JOIN Section22_2_PMLU ON Section22_2_Data.[PMLU_Code] = Section22_2_PMLU.[PMLU_Code]
WHERE (((Section22_2_PMLU.PMLU_Code) Is Null))
```

Comment: normally I would have used Unbound dropdown However, there is VBA behind this dropdown Any suggestions:                                                       Private Sub PMLU_Code_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
  If NotAddDefault(Me.PMLU_Code.Value, _
                   IIf(IsNull(Me.PMLU_Code.OldValue), "", Me.PMLU_Code.OldValue), _
                   "section22_2", Me.NewRecord, "PMLU_Code", "Values For PMLU Exist", False) Then
    Cancel = True
    Me.Undo
    Call GetToRec
  Else
    PMLUHolder = Me.PMLU_Code.Value
  End If
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to refresh the table which fixed the issue

```
Private Sub btnRefresh_Click()

    Dim strSQL As String

    strSQL = "INSERT INTO Section22_2_PMLU ( PMLU_Code )
        SELECT DISTINCT Section22_2_Data.PMLU_Code
        FROM Section22_2_Data LEFT JOIN Section22_2_PMLU ON Section22_2_Data.[PMLU_Code] = Section22_2_PMLU.[PMLU_Code]
        WHERE (((Section22_2_PMLU.PMLU_Code) Is Null));"
    CurrentDb().Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
    ' Next 3 only to ensure the append is commited to the table '
    ' before requerying '
    DoEvents
    DBEngine.Idle dbRefreshCache
    DoEvents

    Me.Requery

End Sub
```